# Get url of Orchard default pages

Tags: url, model-view-controller, orchardcms, httpcontext

I am using orchard 1.9 and I am building a service in which I need to get current URL.

I have OrchardServices and from that I can get the URL like so:

```
_orchardServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
```

This works like a charm for pages/routes that I have created but when I go to the Login or register page (/Users/Account/LogOn) the absolute URL is / and I can't find anyway to get the URL or at least any indication that I am in the LogOn or Register.

Anyone knows how I could get the full url?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what your're asking, you could use the `ItemAdminLink` from the `ContentItemExtension` class.

You will need to add references to `Orchard.ContentManagement`, `Orchard.Mvc.Html` and `Orchard.Utility.Extensions`, but then you will have access to the `@Html` and `@Url` helpers.

From there you will have the ability to get the link to the item using:
`@Html.ItemDisplayLink((ContentItem)Model.ContentItem)`

The link to the item with the Url as the title using: `@Url.ItemDisplayUrl((ContentItem)Model.ContentItem)`

And you should get the same for the admin area by using these:

```
@Html.ItemAdminLink((ContentItem)Model.ContentItem)
@Url.ItemAdminUrl((ContentItem)Model.ContentItem)
```

They will give you relative paths, e.g. `'/blog/blog-post-1'`, but it sounds like you've already got a partial solution for that sorted, so it would be a matter of combining the two.

Although I'm sure there are (much) better ways of doing it, you could get the absolute URL using:

```
String.Format("{0}{1}", WorkContext.CurrentSite.BaseUrl, yourRelativeURL);
```

...but if anyone has a more elegent way of doing it then post a comment below.

Hope that helps someone.